# displaying words from db as links in php

Tags: php, href, echo

i have words like 123.com , 234.org in database
how to display them as links?

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","123");
mysql_select_db("www",$con);

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Tag");

for ($c=0; $c< mysql_num_rows($result); $c++)
{
$f=mysql_fetch_array($result);

###########echo $f['name']." ";
}
 mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to output the HTML for a link. Something along the lines of:

```
print "<a href=\"" . $url . "\">" . $f['name'] . "</a>";
```

replacing url with the site URL you want the link to go to. It sounds like it might also be  $f['name'].

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<a href="'.$f['name'].'">'.$f['name'].'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

links are html.

```
echo '<a href="'.$f['name']'.">Click me</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Tag");

while($f=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<a href='" . $f['name'] . "'>" . $f['name'] . "</a>";
} 
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

A link in html code looks like this:

```
<a href="123.com">123</a>
```

The php you are using only outputs this to html:

```
123.com
```